# Can I take out a sefer and not learn from it?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, jewish-books, sefer-torah

There is an issue with taking out a sefer Torah and not learning/reading from it, as it is disrespectful to the sefer.

Does such a concern exist by other sefarim?

I ask because I know that for some halachos, sefarim are compared to a sefer Torah, like the opinion of the Rosh that purchasing sefarim can be a fulfillment of the mitzvah to write a sefer Torah.

Comment: I don't know (which is why I'm not posting this as an answer). But I have heard that some have the custom of using a _sefer kodesh_ that fell on the floor in order to respect it.

Answer (score 2):

[There are cases where you can use a sefer for not learning](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YDoeeehJF-AC&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=%20lesser%20kedushah&source=bl&ots=N2vZxA5qtT&sig=TcCkp1qDkQT4KOFMxFYMe_J46Nk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VFD7U7rcPJHkavmBgZAE&ved=0CFEQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=lesser%20kedushah%3Dfalse&f=false) for example you can use another sefer (of equal or less kedusha) to raise the height of the sefer one is learning from. However I couldn't find anything that said *specifically* that you can't take out a sefer and not learn from it.

In general we should be sure to show great honor and reverence to sefarim, similar to that accorded to Tefillin. [Sefer Chassidim 917 / Beit Yosef O.C. 240:6]

So your litmus test needs to be "Am I treating the Sefer in a respectful manner even though I am not learning from it ?" If yes, e.g cleaning it from dust before Pesach then you don't need to learn from it.

For a list of things that shouldn't be done with seforim  you can read this article by [Rabbi Ari Elkin](http://www.torahmusings.com/2011/05/sefarim-part-i-of-ii/)  He also helps to understand the relationship between a sefer torah and seforim.

Here is a Maaseh Rav from Reb Ahron of Belz ZT"L

> The previous Belzer Rebbe - Reb Ahron ZT"L had many personal chumros
>   including how he would act with Sefrom. If he asked his gabbai to
>   bring a certain gemorah (or any sefer) to him and by accident another gemorah was
>   brought then he had the gabbai learn a few lines from the gemorah
>   before putting it back and getting the correct one.

Answer (score -1):

I didnt see anyone who say that taking a book out is a disrespectful behavior.
BUT in Shabat it maybe a Borer Problem- if you use it then there is no problem at all. But when you just take it out- I saw some Achronim that says it a Borer.

Rav Neuwirth in Shemirat Shabbat Kehilchatah says its a problem only if thay stands one up on another but if they stands one near the other there is no problem at all.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I think the borer problem is irrespective of whether or not you learn from it.

Comment: I agree, but it reminded me that Shabat Rule and I thought he might want to consider it as well...